# Which copy of storm.yaml file in the storm cluster is used by storm nimbus and supervisor daemons?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm running a storm cluster and I made some changes in the storm.yaml file. I need to decide whether to update the storm.yaml file across all nodes each time I make a change.

Do the daemons at each node use their respective local copies of config files or, is the one saved at nimbus node effective for all?

Comment: You might be on the wrong StackExchange site :) Does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792049/running-storm-nimbus-and-supervisor-on-the-same-physical-node-in-cluster-mode?rq=1

Comment: @jhhoff02 Thanks but the link doesn't seem to answer my question. And sorry, but could you tell me why this appears to be posted on the wrong StackExchange site?

Comment: It sounds like you have a question about gaming, this site might help 
http://gaming.stackexchange.com/
StackOverflow is for issues with programming/development specifically

Comment: @jhhoff02 please notice the tag "apache-storm" in my question. Apache Storm is a distributed real-time data computation system. Let me know if I can make changes to this question to make this more apparent.

Comment: You might get a quick answer to this question by posting this to the storm-users mailing list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each daemon uses its local copy of `storm.yaml`. Thus, Nimbus and Supervisor share the same file, if they run on the same machine. Worker JVM always run on the same machine as their corresponding supervisor and thus, always share the same file.

Hence, if you only change Nimbus related parameters, there is no need to distribute `storm.yaml` over all supervisor nodes. If you change Supervisor parameters and want all Supervisors to "see" the same new configuration, you will need to distribute the file over all nodes (you need to restart the Supervisors, too).

Comment: Thank you. Does the same apply for log4j configuration settings stored in cluster.xml and worker.xml? I launch my topologies from the node that has nimbus. Will the supervisors and workers in different nodes use respective local copies or the ones stored at nimbus node?

Comment: Always local copies. However, it is possible to overwrite the value from local copies at runtime: https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.1/dynamic-log-level-settings.html